# Easiest way of casting List<Descendant> to List<Base>

Tags: c#, .net, list, collections

I have a class structure like this:

```
abstract class Base{}
class Descendant : Base{}
```

I have another class that needs a list of type `List<Base>`. I know I can just add `Descendant` instances to a `List<Base>` but I'd think it'd be preferable to keep stronger-typing here.

What is the easiest way of casting from `List<Descendant>` to `List<Base>`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use LINQ:

```
List<Descendant> descendants = ...;

descendants.Cast<Base>().ToList();
```

Comment: You should also look for generic covariance and contravariance

Comment: Hmmm. It appears Mono for some reason does not have the `.Cast` method :(

Comment: Even if you add "using System.Linq;" ?

Comment: @Foole ah, the trick is (maybe) to use System.Linq and also make a reference to `System.Core`

Comment: @Earlz: Note that you will have two separate lists pointing to the same objects (unless they're value types), i.e. adding or removing items from one list will not affect the other, but changing the inner state of an object in one list will be seen in both lists. This is unlike casting where you're dealing with the same object (in this case, the same list). So this answer doesn't cast the list as you originally requested, but if the behavior of it is acceptable in your situation then it's is indeed the easiest way (so +1).

Comment: On the other hand, if you want to use the same instance and perform a real cast to `List<Base>`, then have a look at .NET 4.0's [Covariance and Contravariance in Generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx), as coding4beer suggested.

Comment: @Allon that is a very good thing to note. For my application though it is ok to have this behavior